# opera mini - problem with loading page

Tags: html, xhtml, opera, wap, opera-mini

I'm developing xhtml page for wap applications and have a problem with the first page load in Opera Mini. Not the entire page content is displayed correctly the first time on screen, a lot of graphics elements are absent.

But right after the page refresh everything is displayed correctly. How to solve this problem during the first page loading ?

Comment: That is strange, is the first page load any slower/faster than the subsequent.  The Opera Mini clients uses servers at the backend to render the page, so just because it's broken now means they will still be able to fix it on their backend without having to release a  new client version.

Comment: Also, when I have moved all css styles from external file to the <head> of html page, everything works perfectly. Something is broken with loading css styles from external file. But I want to leave my css in my styles.css file.

Comment: A typical solution would be to automatically include the css data in the page using server side script - for example, google's mod_pagespeed for Apache does this - http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/filter-css-inline.html

Comment: David, thanks for this solution, but unfortunately my css file is a quite big and I want to leave it in separated file. I have analized some other wap resources and found the similar problem with loading background images from external css files. I have created bug report for this problem. How quickly Opera team can react on this ?

Comment: other similar problem - http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/1077682

Comment: What's the bug's number? I'm afraid WAP doesn't have super-high priority development-wise these days.

Answer (score 0):

Are the images absent entirely, or do they appear as colored boxes first?

When using Opera Mini on a slow connection, the page will often load with colored boxes instead of images. The images will quickly appear if you scroll or reload the page. They'll also appear if you wait several seconds. That's how Opera Mini is *intended* to work.

If what I've described above *isn't* what's happening, let us know, and consider [filing a bug report](https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/).

Comment: I have created bug report with the ID: SKIRNE-144876

Comment: My connection is 10MB/s, I have reproduced this bug in Opera Mini on my Nokia n96, HTC Sensation and Iphone 4 and in online Opera Mini simulator. Also, if I have moved css styles from external file into HTML page everything works correctly even without page refresh. How quickly this problem  could be solved by Opera team ?